# Text bar hover not working after it is clicked one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just started doing some web dev on my own and trying to experiment with the basic HTML,CSS and JS. I'm trying to make search bar with changes color on hovering but after one click it does not changes its color. I have uploaded my code on CodePen. Need some guidance, thank you!

https://codepen.io/Usmaneeyy/pen/PoPwqgm

This is my HTML code for the SearchBar i want to create:

```
<body>
  <div class="topBar">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href=" "><img src="images/logo.png" style="height: 40px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="searchBar">
      <input id="textBar" placeholder="Search.." onclick="expand();" type="text" name="searchedItem" onblur="reset();">

    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;

  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.topBar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 41px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#searchBar input {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 140px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  /*border: none;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 150px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

#searchBar input:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

And this is my JS code:

```
function expand() {
  var x = document.getElementById("textBar");
  x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  x.style.width = "300px";
  x.style.borderRadius = "10px";
  x.style.outline = "none";
}

function reset() {
  var x = document.getElementById("textBar");
  x.value = "";
  x.style.width = "150px";
  x.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  x.style.borderRadius = "10px";
  x.style.outline = "none";
}
```

Comment: You're adding background through the style attribute which will override the background change on hover, because styles in the style attribute are more specific.

Comment: @ZohirSalak can you please elaborate?

Comment: The `reset` and `expand` functions are adding styles to the style attribute, as you might know styles in the style attribute will take priority over styles applied through classes and id's and other means, instead of applying styles directly like that, use a prepared classes and toggle between them.

Comment: Okay i think i got it. Thanks a lot! @ZohirSalak